# search-ui: Load 120 records but then revert back to 20 per page

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

i'm creating infinite scrolling for my ElasticSearch app, which is using the [search-ui](https://github.com/elastic/search-ui/blob/master/ADVANCED.md) package.

This is a component created in **Vue.js**

I have got an Observer, once this is in view I increase the page number, rather than replace my entire results array I append to it, which in turn creates infinite scrolling.

**current** is the current page.
**lastRequestId** is the last request
**requestId** is the current request

> The below is in a different component, so I send the page increase Event back to the root component.

```js
new IntersectionObserver(() => {
    if (this.lastRequestId !== this.requestId) {
        window.EventBus.$emit('search-set-page', this.current + 1)
        this.lastRequestId = this.requestId
    }
}, {
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1.0
}).observe(this.$refs.bottomOfResults);
```

This is the root component, I have just pulled out the key code which does the logic.

```js
window.EventBus.$on('search-set-page', page => {
    if (page < 1 || page > this.state.totalPages) {
        console.error('You tried to change to a page that doesn\'t exist...');
        return;
    }
    this.setCurrentPage(page)
});

this.driver = new SearchDriver({});

// This is where it does the results appending logic.
this.driver.subscribeToStateChanges(state => {
    this.state = state
    this.current = state.current
    if (!this.results[state.requestId] && state.results.length) {
        this.$set(this.results, state.requestId, state.results)
    }
    this.requestId = state.requestId
});

setCurrentPage(page) {
    this.current = page;
    this.driver.setCurrent(page);
},
```

### My Problem?

Well, lets say I have scrolled down to load 7 pages worth of documents. If I refresh I now need to load these again and send the visitor to where they refreshed, I can set the results per page to `current * results per page` which works fine.

But due to API delays and other timing issues i'm struggling to set this back once the results have returned. I tried adding a `setTimeout` and then changing the `resultsPerPage` AND `current` however it was changing the `resultsPerPage` first, which just results in duplicate records being returned, and it never changed the `current`.

Anyone got any experience in this?